# WebRTC Joining room

Tags: webrtc

Currently developing a WebRTC app,(local at the moment),

I used the codes of Muaz Khan as a starting point, [Muaz Khan GitHiub](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment)

My problem is when i quick join the room with multiple tabs on my screen, +/- 1/5 does not join the room.
This does not happen all the time but alot.
when i reload the tab wich did not joined, and try it again, it works fine.

My own project has the problem and the muaz khan demo has it too.

The error in console log:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

the function in the WebRTC library:

```
function isEmpty(session) {
    var stringified = JSON.stringify(session);
    if (stringified === '{}' || !stringified.split(',').length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can't find what's wrong because this error happens often, but not every time..

Answer (score 0):

So, you're talking about [this](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/dev/globals.js#L77).

I'll suggest following demo, which is having following advantages:

1. Reliable connection for open/join rooms. It NEVER fails.
2. Auto reconnects if socket.io connection fails.
3. Reliably keeps room opened even if moderator leaves.

To install it in linux based systems:

```
mkdir rmc && cd rmc
wget https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/packages/rtcmulticonnection-client.tar
tar -xf rtcmulticonnection-client.tar
node server
```

Now it runs on port `8080`.

You can even directly download the [TAR](https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/packages/rtcmulticonnection-client.tar) or [ZIP](https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/packages/rtcmulticonnection-client.zip).

Comment: your project demo does not have /socket.io/socket.io.js
and /reliable-signaler/signaler.js

Comment: Socket.io is already included in the package. You simply need to open "Node.js command prompt tool" (via nodejs.org) and run these commands: `cd target-directory && node server` Now you can open port "8080" in localhost.

Comment: I really don't know what i have to do with that node_modules file. i have run every npm i found on tutorials. the link in the index file are wrong. there is no socket.io.js file in the whole project. My project runs on wamp at the moment, i have read all the docs from rtcmulticonnection, but nodeJS is still new for me

Comment: i tried to fix that project for hours now, downloaded new socket.io, the node server command worked, when i press join room i get 4 huge errors from the rtcmulticonnection lib. you sure this workes?

Comment: It is node.js based demo and it works fine. Socket.io URL is this: `localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`. Again, it isn't PHP based demo. It is node.js based demo. If you're invoking code from PHP, then use full URL e.g. `http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`.